# ion-slides bad placement after screen orientation change

Tags: css, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I have an app with several pages. In the main one (MainPage) there is an `ion-header` consisting of an `ion-navbar` with a button, an image and one `ion-slide`. Together I'm using a special version of this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) (content of `package.json`):

`"cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "git+https://github.com/8eo/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation.git#fix-unlock"`

**Goal:** The general idea is to achieve a specific screen orientation behavior in the app with this requirements:

1. MainPage should be always be seen in portrait mode. Landscape is not allowed.
2. Whenever I turn the device, I should navigate to OtherPage.
3. Inside OtherPage I should be able to turn as many times as I want, whithout navigating to any page, just keeping rotating the same OtherPage.
4. If I click cross button, I should navigate back to MainPage which should be in portrait mode.
5. Rest of pages in the application can only be seen in portrait mode (these pages are not shown here).

**Problem:** Focusing in point 4, when I navigate back to MainPage from OtherPage, the slider in the header is bad placed. You can see a demo in the below attached gif:

[image]

This is my current HTML:

```
<ion-header no-border>
    <ion-navbar class="main-header">
        <button ion-button class="sidemenu-button absolute-button" menuToggle>
            <div class="menu-button-wrapper">
                <div class="menu-button-upper"></div>
                <div class="menu-button-lower"></div>
            </div>
        </button>

        <div class="header-logo">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/16/16">
        </div>

        <ion-slides #propertySlides slidesPerView="2" centeredSlides="true"
                    (ionSlideDidChange)="updateSlides()">
            <ion-slide>
                <p>Cat 1</p>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<!-- No elements here -->
</ion-content>
```

In the app component I control the screen orientation behavior of the app. Can be a bit tricky. The `isOverlay` property is for skip and no doing anything with modal shown with a loading spinner:

```
private setOrientationListener() {
    this.screenSrv.subscribeChanges().subscribe(
        () => {
            this.onOrientationChange(MainPage, OtherPage);
        }
    );
}

private setViewListeners() {
    this.app.viewWillEnter.subscribe(viewCtrl => {
        if (!(viewCtrl.isOverlay)) {
            if ((viewCtrl.id === MainPage.id) || (viewCtrl.id === OtherPage.id)) {
                this.screenSrv.releaseOrientation();
            } else {
                this.screenSrv.forceOrientation(this.screenSrv.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, false);
            }
        } else {
            this.screenSrv.releaseOrientation();
        }
    });

    this.app.viewDidEnter.subscribe(viewCtrl => {
        if (!(viewCtrl.isOverlay)) {
            if (!(viewCtrl.id === MainPage.id) && !(viewCtrl.id === OtherPage.id)) {
                this.screenSrv.forceOrientation(this.screenSrv.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, false);
            }
        } else {
            this.screenSrv.releaseOrientation();
        }
    });

    this.app.viewWillLeave.subscribe(viewCtrl => {
        if (!(viewCtrl.isOverlay)) {
            if (!(viewCtrl.id === MainPage.id)) {
                this.screenSrv.forceOrientation(this.screenSrv.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, true);
            } else {
                this.screenSrv.releaseOrientation();
            }
        } else {
            this.screenSrv.releaseOrientation();
        }
    });
}

private onOrientationChange(portraitComponentName: string, landscapeConponentName: string) {
    let newOrientation = this.screenSrv.getCurrentOrientation();
    let pageInstance = this.app.getRootNav().getActive();
    if (this.authSrv.isUserAuthed()) {
        if (this.screenSrv.isLandscapeOrientation(newOrientation)) {
            if (pageInstance.id === portraitComponentName) {
                this.navCtrl.push(landscapeConponentName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The boolean parameter in the `forceOrientation()` function means that the screen orientation is locked only during a few seconds. After those seconds, the orientation is released automatically.

I call this two methods like this:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.setViewListeners();
    this.setOrientationListener();
});
```

**Guesses:**

- Tried putting the ion-slides inside ion-content, just in case the rendering inside the header works different.
- Tried removing any CSS classes applied to the element.
- Checked that the we unsubscribe from the observables on `ionViewWillLeave()` lifecycle, just in case there is too much script work in the background.

**Note:**
Can only test in a real physical device. Screen orientation changes doesn't trigger in Chrome.

If anyone could shed light on this with any small hint, it would be very helpful.

**Edit:**

- Tried removing Ionic ion-slides and use Swiper library directly. Seems that the behavior is the same! Maybe the problems is in this library and not in Ionic component.